# Creating a new git remote origin in Aptana Studio causes it to hang

Tags: git

I have installed Aptana Studio 3 with Git version 1.8.4-preview20130916 (this version was installed by Aptana Studio).

When I try to connect to a remote repository Aptana hangs.

I am doing the following:

I right click on the project, then select: Team -> Remotes -> Add...
New remote name: origin
Remote URI: git@gitlab.alfatron.com.au:anthony/apttest.git

The IDE then locks up indefinitely.

How can I add a remote git repository in Aptana Studio without locking up the IDE?

Comment: Have you tried using the terminal?